Hasura Table/View Relationship in metadata files
I need to make a relationship between a table and a view in hasura metadata files. I'm doing this because I've tried to make a relationship between tables that located on different schema and it response, the other table is not tracked (?) or something like that. So I made a view that query a join between one table to the table that located in other schema, and now I confused on how to make the table and view have a relationship so I can do GQL query to them. Or is there any better ways to do this kind of thing ?
Thanks before guys.
I've tried to make a relationship between table with different schema and it response the table is not tracked. so I create a view on schema a with a query selecting table on schema a joined to schema b. still got no luck and they response, query can't be done because there is no foreign key between them.
My Expectation:
I can do GQL Query to table a in schema a and join them to table b in schema b.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
